# Azure Web app connect to VM service on private network

Tags: azure, networking, virtualization

I've created windows server virtual machine with active directory controller and my web app is communicating with it on public ip successfully (by ldap), but when i try connect to ldap on private ip (virtual network) it does not respond

to my Web app i have set VNet Configuration 
[image: ![enter image description here]

my virtual machine network tab:

[image]

But it does not work when i try to connect to ldap://10.0.1.4:389

What should i do?

I can't even test my connection between webapp (by tcpping) and vm neither on public and private ip

i couldn't add to my webapp vnet integration on 10.0.1.0/24 because there was written that this subnet is already in use (or sth like that)

what should i type when i do vnet integration?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

heh...
i've created second virtual network, and integrated web app with it...
next i have connected my second virtual network to first and... everything works great, ping's are < 1 ms...
that's a bit embarassing that it did not work when both web app and virtual machine were in one virtual network and i don't know why

Answer (score 0):

VNet Integration with Azure web app is required a dedicated unused subnet for the network connection. The subnet should be a subnet where no other resources like Azure VM located.

Your configuration is correct. You could follow [these troubleshooting steps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-integrate-with-vnet#troubleshooting) to verify if the VNet integration is working well. You can test via port 3389 on Azure VM. In my case, there is **not** a DC deployed on Azure VM.

[image]

However, please note that

> There are some things that VNet Integration doesn't support, like:
>
> - Mounting a drive.
> - **Active Directory integration**.
> - NetBIOS.

Thus, I suppose Idap does not work with VNet Integration.

Comment: but i have not active directory as SaaS from Azure, i have installed it manually on virtual machine... i also can not ping on lan even on RDP port...

Comment: Azure web app can not support ping, you could use tcpping tool in the console of app service like my screenshot to verify it. Also, you may have a look at providing links.

Comment: yes, i have used tcpping, but it does not work,
i have readen this article before i posted question, but everything look's ok...

Comment: Could you deploy another new Azure VM in another subnet( does not join any domain) but in the same VNet as your app integrated subnet? Then you can use tcpping tool to verify this VNet integration function without the AD environment.

Comment: now ping on vm's public add ip (with LDAP port) works, but private not :(

Comment: now ping on vm's public add ip (with LDAP port) works, but private not :(
i also can't ping default gateway from my vm (10.0.1.4) = > (10.0.1.1)

Comment: Where do you ping from and to? and Do you try tcpping with a port from the Azure VM in the integrated vnet?

Comment: by console from azure app (which is integrated with virtual network) to my virtual machine which is already in this network (network was automatically created on virtual machine created)